# How detect visibility of element that previously was invisible in the browser?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, browser

I am working on a small analytic app (using JavaScript) and faced the following problem: the site has invisible elements that at some point become visible. For example, [like here](https://www.wildearth.com.au/). At the top there is a menu, when you hover the mouse, a submenu appears. It is necessary to detect when the links inside the submenu are visible to the user. The submenu is rendered by CSS when `hover` the element in the main menu. The structure of the site is initially unknown, so I can't put handlers on the necessary elements, the solution should work for any site.

I've already tried / know:

1. If you check the CSS property of the link inside the submenu via `window.getComputedStyle(element).display`, then it shows that the element is visible. Only zero values ​​in `element.getBoundingClientRect()` indicate that the element is currently invisible.
2. I thought that `MutationObserver` would help, but it turned out that in this case there is no DOM change, so the observer does not work.

What other solutions could there be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who face same problem, I solved it by using [IntersectionObserver API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API). Example:

```js
const onIntersectionChange = (entries, observer) => {
    entries.forEach(entry => {
        if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            //Element become visible. Do your logic here and remove monitoring
            observer.unobserve(entry.target);
        }
    });
};

const intersectionObserver = new IntersectionObserver(onIntersectionChange, {
    threshold: 0.5
});

watchingElements.forEach(element => {
    intersectionObserver.observe(element);
});
```